# I got this error: The argument type 'DateTime?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DateTime'

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I get this error on the date row:

The argument type 'DateTime?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DateTime'.

This is the code:

```
                          icon: task.taskImage,
                          title: task.tasktitle,
                          time: task.startTime,
                          desc: task.taskDesc,
                          ifDate: true,
                          date: task.taskDate!=null? DateFormat.yMMMd().format(task.taskDate): DateFormat.yMMMd()  as String,
                        ),
```

I couldn't figure out how to correct.
Can you tell me hot to correct the code, please?

Comment: check https://dart.dev/codelabs/null-safety

Answer (score 6):

To turn a nullable type into a non-nullable you can add `!` to it, although it throws an error if it happens to be null.

In this case `format()` requires a non-nullable type. Since you made sure `task.taskDate` is not null you can safely apply that operator. So do

```
DateFormat.yMMMd().format(task.taskDate!)
```